# Windows Installer won't let me install anything ?

Tags: windows-7, installation, installer

Trying to install a Silverlight Update, a Java update or other software, I get this window:

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A few things you should take a look at.

1. Make sure you have full administrative priviledges on the computer, and make sure you start the installer as administrator. (To make sure, right-click on the icon, and choose "Run as Administrator.")
2. Make sure you download and run the installer for YOUR user folder or from a network share that you have full administrative rights to.
3. If none of this works, go to your start menu and type in: "Disk Cleanup" start the program and select the "Temporary Files" checkbox and start the process. This may help to delete some failed install that you have living on your system and causing the error.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you run sysinternals process explorer, you might be able to see the MS installer process `msiexec.exe` running.  I killed off this process, an then re-attempted the silverlight install and it seemed to install OK.

I can't guarantee that this is the best way to do this though...

Answer (score 1):

Try and restart Windows Installer using the following commands in an elevated command prompt.

```
net stop msiserver
```

then

```
net start msiserver
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a strange one like this were the user had put a file into `C:\Users` which had the same name as their profile. That is the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME` contained their profile but they had a text document called `USERNAME` (no extension) also in `C:\Users`.

Answer (score -1):

Try repairing your file and registry permissions with SubInACL.

1. Download SubInACL from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510
2. Install the program
3. Copy the script at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/09/04/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions/ and execute it as instructed there.